# What does port forwarding of DHCP (ports 67 & 68) accomplish on a home router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, dhcp

I'm helping a friend migrate to a new Wi-Fi router at home, and find that his old router has port forwarding rules in place that route TCP/UDP traffic on external ports 67 & 68 to internal ports 67 & 68 of the router's IP address.

I grasp that these are DHCP ports, and know that the router does act as DHCP server for his LAN.

However, I'm not familiar with this configuration, and don't want to migrate it to the new router until I can wrap my head around it.

Can anyone shine some light on the value, function or potential purposes of providing external access to his in-house DHCP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely: No useful purpose whatsoever.

Very very unlikely: The local DHCP server handles multiple subnets; one is the local LAN and others are remote LANs using *DHCP relay,* which forwards all queries over the Internet to this router. (This allows multiple subnets to have a centrally managed list of known devices.)

(In any case, DHCP is always UDP-based, so if the port-forwarding rules include TCP, I'd lean towards them having been set up by somebody who had no idea what they're doing.)

Comment: Thanks, @grawity. He's certainly not doing anything as fancy as DHCP relay. That said, do you have any opinion on the _safety_ of this configuration on his old router? Is there anything particularly dangerous or potentially insidious about it? I'm trying to be only appropriately paranoid here :)

Comment: No good can come from opening ports that dont need to be opened. Anyone with a security persoective will advise disabling forwarding of ports that are not needed. (that said if the router firmware is set up correctly and the DHCP client is not listening on the LAN port thus forward should have no effect)